# Python Access Violation Writing using ZKteco SDK

Tags: python, ctypes

I've been trying to set some data to a device using the SDK provided by the manufacturer(ZKTECO). Some functions such as connecting, disconnecting, modifying IP address work without any issues but when I try to update data to an internal table I get the following error: `exception: access violation writing 0x000000000205A040`. From what I have researched the most common issue has to do with setting the proper *argtypes* and *restypes*, which I have applied to my understanding. As extra information im using python 3.7 along with Windows 10 pro 64-bit.

Function from document:

```
int SetDeviceData(HANDLE handle,const char *TableName, const char *Data, const char *Options)

int Connect(const char *Parameters)

Void Disconnect(HANDLE handle)
```

Code I have so far:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll, windll, create_string_buffer, c_char_p, c_void_p
from ctypes.wintypes import HANDLE

zk = windll.LoadLibrary("C:/Windows/System32/plcommpro.dll")

zk.Connect.argtypes = [c_char_p]
zk.Connect.restype = HANDLE

zk.SetDeviceData.argtypes = (HANDLE, c_char_p, c_char_p, c_char_p)
zk.SetDeviceData.restypes = ctypes.c_int

zk.Disconnect.argtypes = [HANDLE]
zk.Disconnect.restypes = c_void_p


params = b"protocol=TCP,ipaddress=192.168.100.178,port=4370,timeout=2000,passwd="
params_buf = c_char_p(params)

handler = zk.Connect(params_buf)

string = "Handler is: {0}\n".format(handler)
print(string)


try:
    table = b"user"
    data = b"Pin=9999\tPassword=1793\tName=Test\tStartTime=20190522\tEndTime=2010523"
    options = b""

    table_buf = c_char_p(table)
    data_buf = c_char_p(data)

    ret = zk.SetDeviceData(handler, table_buf, data_buf, options)

    del table_buf
    del data_buf

    result = "Result: {0}".format(ret)
    print(result)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

zk.Disconnect(handler)
```

TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmpdll.py", line 35, in <module>
    ret = zk.SetDeviceData(handler, table, data, options)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x000000005EF65040
```

Comment: What line is the error?  Provide the traceback.  Also what how is `zk` declared?  You don't have to wrap your byte strings in `c_char_p`.  Declaring the `argtypes` wil handle that, so `zk.SetDeviceData(handler,b'user','pin=999\t...2010523',b'')` should be fine.  `options`, since blank, might be `None` if `NULL` is allowed in the C API.

Comment: Also, delete the `try/except` to see the full traceback.

Comment: What are the full C declarations of all three function?

Comment: I've added the traceback and the rest of the DLL functions to the main post(All the info i have on the functions are what I posted and a brief explanation of the parameters). zk is loaded on the first line with `windll`(i've also tried with `cdll` as some other people have used).This line gives the error `zk.SetDeviceData(handler,table,user,options)`

Comment: On 64-bit, cdll/windll don't matter, but if using 32-bit Python only use windll if the function is declared __stdcall calling convention.  Why does the C definition of `Connect` return an `int` but `Disconnect` take a `HANDLE`?  That's not how the Python code declares it so I assume a typo?  Otherwise the code looks correct.  Oh, and `zk.Disconnect.restypes = None` not `c_void_p`. Does passing *the same* parameters in C code work correctly?

Comment: On the documentation it does return an `int`, on another post someone had mentioned setting restpye to `HANDLER`, i changed it back but the problem continues. I have the code working on C#: 
        `public static extern IntPtr Connect(string ConnectHandler);                   
         public static extern int SetDeviceData(IntPtr id, string table, string data, string options);                        
         public static extern int DeleteDeviceData(IntPtr id, string table, string data, string options);`. I havent tried on C.

Comment: `int` and `HANDLE` aren't the same size on 64-bit Python.  That could be the root of the problem.  Your C# code uses IntPtr for the Connect return and as input to the other functions, which agrees.

Comment: I just tried changing both the argtypes and the connect restype to both int and Handle, also i have found a bit of code from some software running in python 2.6 that doesnt seem to set the argtypes and restypes: `def update_data(self, table, data, options):
        ptable = create_string_buffer(table)
        str_buf = create_string_buffer(data)

        ret = self.commpro.SetDeviceData(self.hcommpro, ptable, str_buf, options)

        del ptable
        del str_buf
        return {'result': ret, 'data': ''}`

Comment: I ran the same code in Python 2.6.6 and it worked without a problem, not sure what changed specifically that caused this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there were some issues with how the `handle` was being generated on python 3.7 .

I tested other versions and it seems that after version 3.5 the error occurs, any version below that seems to work as intended.